# 301 redirect with regular expressions: ASP to HTML

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to redirect a certain pattern of URLs (from an old site) to a simpler, newer html version we are using.

The old URLs look like this:

```
http://example.com/Collections.asp?Collection=My Collection
```

...and ideally they would be redirected to:

```
http://example.com/my-collection.html
```

So we have that last word which is variable, and can be one word, more than one word with spaces, more than one word with "-" in between them (hyphenated chain of words), or a simple number, like "3".

I'm pretty new with regular expressions and would need some help to manage it.

I tried with:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /Collections.asp?Collection=(.*) /$1.html
```

...with no luck, and some other variations.

How can I grab that variable word and make it suitable for my new URL structure?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

You can not match against query strings in RedirectMatch directive, Use mod_rewrite :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Collections\.asp\?Collection=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks this looks great. I added a question mark in the last line so ?Collection= is removed, like so: RewriteRule ^ /%1.html? [NC,L,R]. However, the variable collects uppercase letters too, and we'd need only lowercase. Is there a way to fix it?